# Market Basket Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, market-basket-analysis

I have the following pandas dataset of transactions, regarding a retail shop:

```
print(df)

product       Date                   Assistant_name
product_1     2017-01-02 11:45:00    John
product_2     2017-01-02 11:45:00    John
product_3     2017-01-02 11:55:00    Mark
...
```

I would like to **create** the following **dataset**, for Market Basket Analysis:

```
product       Date                   Assistant_name  Invoice_number
product_1     2017-01-02 11:45:00    John            1
product_2     2017-01-02 11:45:00    John            1
product_3     2017-01-02 11:55:00    Mark            2
    ...
```

Briefly, if a transaction has the **same Assistant_name and Date**, I assume it does generate a new Invoice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpliest is [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with joined columns together:

```
df['Invoice'] = pd.factorize(df['Date'].astype(str) + df['Assistant_name'])[0] + 1
print (df)
     product                 Date Assistant_name  Invoice
0  product_1  2017-01-02 11:45:00           John        1
1  product_2  2017-01-02 11:45:00           John        1
2  product_3  2017-01-02 11:55:00           Mark        2
```

If performance is important use `pd.lib.fast_zip`:

```
df['Invoice']=pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.Date.values, df.Assistant_name.values]))[0]+1
```

**Timings**:

```
#[30000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: df['Invoice'] = list(zip(df['Date'], df['Assistant_name']))
     ...: df['Invoice'] = df['Invoice'].astype('category').cat.codes + 1
     ...: 
9.16 ms ± 54.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [179]: %%timeit
     ...: df['Invoice'] = pd.factorize(df['Date'].astype(str) + df['Assistant_name'])[0] + 1
     ...: 
11.2 ms ± 395 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [180]: %%timeit 
     ...: df['Invoice'] = pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.Date.values, df.Assistant_name.values]))[0] + 1
     ...: 
6.27 ms ± 93.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: where can I find documentation for `pd.lib.fast_zip` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` categories is one way:

```
df['Invoice'] = list(zip(df['Date'], df['Assistant_name']))
df['Invoice'] = df['Invoice'].astype('category').cat.codes + 1

#               product      Date Assistant_name  Invoice
# product_1  2017-01-02  11:45:00           John        1
# product_2  2017-01-02  11:45:00           John        1
# product_3  2017-01-02  11:55:00           Mark        2
```

The benefit of this method is you can easily retrieve a dictionary of mappings:

```
dict(enumerate(df['Invoice'].astype('category').cat.categories, 1))
# {1: ('11:45:00', 'John'), 2: ('11:55:00', 'Mark')}
```